# Am I stupid or I just have a faulty USB drive?

Tags: partitioning, usb, usb-drive

Got a new and fancy USB 3.0 32gb thumb drive. Yay!
It seemed to work the first couple days but now Disks gives this error

> Error creating file system: Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sdb" mktable msdos' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Error: Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb
>   Error: Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb
>   Error: Input/output error during write on /dev/sdb
>    (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Gparted gives this

> Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb

and this command hangs in the terminal for without any output for more than an hour and makes my pc run slow (cancelled it after an hour)

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

So, is there hope for my sexy thumb drive or should I cry tonight?

Comment: Did you use dd to create an installer from an ISO. That does not use standard partition table and you then should just need to zero MBR &  partition table. `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=512 count=1`  of course change sdX to correct drive and always double check you have correct drive. dd can be dangerous as there is no undo or recovery.

Comment: No i haven't. I don't know how to do that.
But the dd command you gave gives that:
dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdb’: Input/output error
1+0 records in 
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.00189173 s, 0.0 kB/s

| 

Disks app sees the drive size though

Comment: Now system is not even seeing flash drive in any writable mode. Not sure what else to suggest Several links to similar issues in related in right  panel, but I have not had issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return The USB thumb drive to the store and ask for a swap if it's still under warranty (check the manufacturer's web site) as it looks like it's dead now...

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...*

Comment: I could figure that I should swap it on my own as soon as I'm sure its unfixable.
The question is when one is sure about that?

Comment: If writing 512 bytes with `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=1` doesn't work, you're 99.9999% sure! 30+ years of experience with computers tell me your USB drive is hosed... :-( And don't forget to click the little grey ☑ before you run to the store before the warranty expires...

Comment: Thank you!
The store is in China though :)

Comment: Your home countries warranty laws still apply!  So check your local laws...

Comment: It doesn't. It was ordered over the internet from China. My country has nothing to do with it and will never do anything about it.

Comment: Try the following: (It's dead anyway) Put it in an envelope, return it where it came from and mention reason for returning: DOA!  For the future: by stuff around the corner where you can go and complain to a person...  The most you'll lose now is a stamp and the most you'll gain is a new USB stick.

Comment: Talk to the bank which issues your credit card about 'defective merchandise'

Comment: @K7AAY Another one who started on CP/M...  **:-) ;-) :-)**